# mysql query taking too long to response

Tags: mysql

Why such query in mysql takes too long to respond:

```
select s.sid,s.sname, 
   sum(case WHEN d.dgr_date='2014-12-31' then d.daily_gen end) as dgen,
   round(sum(case WHEN d.dgr_date between '2013-12-01' and last_day
   ('2013-12-31') then d.daily_gen end)/1000000,2) as pmtd
from dgrs d ,locs l, spvs s 
where l.mloc=d.mc_loc and s.sid=l.spid 
group by s.sname;


index: compound(d.dgr_date, d.daily_gen), d.mc_loc(fk:l.mloc), l.mloc, s.sid
Main table: dgrs(400k rows).
```

### Explain of query

```
  id    select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref        rows  Extra
  1     SIMPLE      s       ALL     PRIMARY         NULL    NULL    NULL       20    Using temporary; Using filesort
  1     SIMPLE      l       ref     PRIMARY,fk_spid fk_spid  4      oms.s.sid   9    Using index
  1    SIMPLE       d       ref     fk_mcloc        fk_mcloc 102    oms.l.mloc  485  NULL
```

Comment: Have you done *any* debugging yourself? Have you EXPLAIN'd? Have you tried to remove stuff until it's faster? Have you tried JOIN's instead?

Comment: Yes, I tried, each time i'm getting long response from mysql.

Comment: Did you miss "Using temporary; Using filesort" on `s`? Probably because of your `group by s.sname`?

Comment: Should i need to apply Using temporary; Using filesort" on s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use an indexed field in the `GROUP BY` clause. I guess `s`.`sid` is the `PK` of table `spvs`. Use it instead of `s`.`sname`.
2. Make sure the fields that appear in the `WHERE` clause are indexed.
3. Put an index on column `dgr_date` and move the conditions from the second `CASE` into the where clause:

   ```
   SELECT s.sid, s.sname, 
       SUM(IF(d.dgr_date = '2014-12-31', d.daily_gen, 0)) as dgen,
       ROUND(SUM(d.daily_gen)/1000000, 2) AS pmtd
   FROM dgrs d, locs l, spvs s 
   WHERE l.mloc = d.mc_loc
       AND s.sid = l.spid 
       AND d.dgr_date BETWEEN '2013-12-01' AND '2013-12-31'
   GROUP BY s.sid
   ```

Comment: My only concern is if there are multiple common "sname" values for different "sid" values... I doubt it, but I have seen it and your on target with what I would have suggested...

Comment: Good point. I didn't think about it but, indeed, having the same value on `sname` for different `sid` also produces the wrong result.

Comment: By understanding your point, i did the compound index on dgrs (mc_loc, dgr_date) where only mc_loc is the connecting point which was earlier not indexed. That resolved the issue and query returned in .19sec. Thanks alot for hint.

Answer (score 0):

mysql [`join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) may decrease response time

```
select s.sid,s.sname, 
   sum(case WHEN d.dgr_date='2014-12-31' then d.daily_gen end) as dgen,
   round(sum(case WHEN d.dgr_date between '2013-12-01' and last_day
   ('2013-12-31') then d.daily_gen end)/1000000,2) as pmtd
  from dgrs d 
   inner join locs l on l.mloc=d.mc_loc 
   inner join spvs s on and s.sid=l.spid
group by s.sname;
```